# DI Error in Angular2 component

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular2-services

[image: Any help please i got this error when i try to inject the service to my component]

i got this error when i try to inject the service to my component

1. I created my service and decorated it with @Injectable()
2. I added my service to my app.module in providers
3. I tried to use the service in my component and inject it using the constructor

   but it gave me this error 
   [image: The Service]

[image: The App.moudle]

[image: the component]

Comment: code of the component / service / module would help

Comment: @MichaelLaffargue done check the images

Comment: Add `import: [HttpModule]`

Comment: @yurzui thanks it worked

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot to add `HttpModule` to `imports` array

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    ...
```